# How to print last word in a sentence after equal to or back slash in php

Tags: php

I have a form where users need to supply youtube video links in either of this two format below
**http://youtbe.com/your_video_id**

**http://youtbe.com/v?=your_video_id**

I am trying to get the last word after either equal to(=) or backword slash(/) from the form input.

I have tried the code below and it works only if i write the codes seperately as per line of code below.

```
$video1=strip_tags($_POST['video']);
// get last string in video after equal to
$video = substr($video1, strrpos($video1, '=') + 1);
// get last string in video after backward slash
$video = substr($video1, strrpos($video1, '/') + 1);
```

My problem is that since user can send a youtube video link with video id either coming after equal sign or backward slash. How do I get the last youtube video id(ie the last word occurrence in the sentence)

Comment: just split the input once by `=`, and once by `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$string='http://youtbe.com/152';
//$string='http://youtbe.com/v?=152';

//checks the index of the string
if (strpos($string, '/v?') !== false) {
    $string=explode('=',$string);
    print_r($string[1]);
    echo "first IF";
}
else{
    $string=explode('/',$string);
    print_r($string[3]);
    echo "second IF";
}
```

Try this code. Comment and uncomment the strings i used to see that it works for both examples.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use regular expression too..

```
preg_match( '/[\w]+$/', $video1, $match) ;
```